# Adding data dynamically in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

My setup is to have a graph online, and then get a new graph (via Ajax calls to a server) and use it to update the online graph. For example, I may want to include only those nodes that are in both graphs.

I would like to use the built-in set functions (here: http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/building--filtering) for manipulating the old and new graphs, but I need two collections to do it. If I add the new graph to the `cy` object collection, then the nodes are drawn immediately, and I can't reference them as a new collection.

My solution was to have a separate `cy` object and then use set operations between these two collections. But as my example shows, it's not working as expected. It's not just animation, that's a just a toy use case. I may want to remove those nodes, or move them to a specific location.

For some reason, this doesn't work. Namely, `just2` is not colored blue as I would hope. Can anyone explain why not, and what I need to do to fix it?

```
var cy = cytoscape({

    container: document.getElementById('cy'), // container to render in

    style: [ // the stylesheet for the graph
        {
            selector: 'node',
            style: {
                'background-color': '#666',
                'label': 'data(id)'
            }
        },
    ],

    elements: {
        nodes: [
            { data: { id: 'n0' } },
            { data: { id: 'n1' } },
            { data: { id: 'n2' } },

        ],
            edges: [
            { data: { source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } },
            { data: { source: 'n1', target: 'n2' } }
        ]
    },
    layout: {
        name: 'grid'
    },

});

// Add new data here -- potentially the result of an Ajax call.
var newarray = [
    { data: { id: 'n0' } },
    { data: { id: 'n8' } },
    { data: { id: 'n9' } },
    { data: { source: 'n8', target: 'n9' } },
];

var cy2 = cytoscape(
    {
        elements: newarray,
        headless: true,
        renderer: { name: null }
    });

var el = cy.elements();
var cy2el = cy2.elements();

var both = el.intersection(cy2el);
var justel = el.difference(cy2el);
var just2 = cy2el.difference(el);

cy.add(cy2el);

// This works.
both.animate({
    style: { "background-color" : "yellow" }
}, {
    duration: 500,
});

// This works. 
justel.animate({
    style: { "background-color" : "red" }
}, {
    duration: 500,
});

// This does not work.
just2.animate({
    style: { "background-color" : "blue" }
}, {
    duration: 500,
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm relatively new to answering questions...so I hope I'm doing this the right way by adding another answer as opposed to completely changing the first one...

Given your clarification, it seems like the best, most efficient, and sensible approach would be to only use one graph and add new data to it as you go.  If you add a data element that identifies the batch or update, that will allow you to do all the things you seem to want to do as far as set operations simply by using the new selector, which you could add on the fly as needed.  Does this example make sense to you?

```
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  elements: {
    nodes: [{
      data: {
        id: 'n0',
        batchID: 'b0'
      },
      classes: '.original_nodes'
    }, {
      data: {
        id: 'n1',
        batchID: 'b0'
      },
      classes: '.original_nodes'
    }, {
      data: {
        id: 'n2',
        batchID: 'b0'
      },
      classes: '.original_nodes'
    }],
    edges: [{
      data: {
        id: 'e0',
        batchID: 'b0',
        source: 'n0',
        target: 'n1'
      },
      classes: '.orginal_edges'
    }, {
      data: {
        id: 'e1',
        batchID: 'b0',
        source: 'n1',
        target: 'n2'
      },
      classes: '.orginal_edges'
    }]
  },
  style: [{
    // This is now essentially your default for the graph
    selector: 'node',
    style: {
      'background-color': '#666',
      'label': 'data(id)
    }
  }, {
    // This is for the original batch
    selector: '.original_nodes',
    style: {
      'background-color': '#666',
      'label': 'data(id)
    }
  }],
  layout: {
    name: 'grid'
  }
);


// Add new data here -- potentially the result of an Ajax call.
// Also, might want to reformat the array to be better ingested and more explicit about which ones are nodes or edges

var newarray = [{
  group: 'nodes',
  classes: '.b1_nodes',
  data: {
    id: 'n0',
    batchID: 'b1'
  }
}, {
  group: 'nodes',
  classes: '.b1_nodes',
  data: {
    id: 'n8',
    batchID: 'b1'
  }
}, {
  group: 'nodes',
  classes: '.b1_nodes',
  data: {
    id: 'n9',
    batchID: 'b1'
  }
}, {
  group: 'edges',
  classes: '.b1_edges',
  data: {
    id: 'e2',
    batchID: 'b1',
    source: 'n8',
    target: 'n9'
  }
}];

// Now, before we add the new data, let's create the new selector
cy.style().selector('.b1_nodes').style({
  'background-color': 'blue'
}).update();

cy.add(newarray);
```

Comment: I was afraid that it would come to this. It's a little awkward to include an id for each batch, but it seems to be the best solution!

Comment: Well, adding a batchID could be done relatively easily once you return your new graph elements from your Ajax call.  Simply loop through each element and add a batch ID...certainly less code than your first take at doing this...

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, it would be great if you could mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially two things going on here, but your question is not clear enough to know what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Are you simply trying to create *one* graph and the add nodes/edges to it?

To solve the issue you say does not work with just2.animate, you are using the wrong function.  Animate is not for animating style transitions.  For that use-case you would simply add to your stylesheet using the transition animation properties found here: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/transition-animation.

For the bigger issue...are you intentionally creating two separate graphs and then working with the two in combination?  Or is your intent to create a single graph and add elements to it with the second batch of elements having a different color than the first?

If the latter, then you can simply add the newArray elements to the first cytoscape instance and use another style selector to give them a different color.

It would be much easier to help you if you could be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.